# Refs from Class Component to Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am in the process of converting a file from a class component to a functional component.

```
let embellishmentRefs = createRef<AddArtEmbellishmentEntry>();

useEffect(() => {
        const embellishments = Object.assign([], props.orderLinesDetailed[0].embellishments);

        embellishments.forEach((embellishment, i) => {
            embellishment.Id = i;
            const ref: React.RefObject<AddArtEmbellishmentEntry> = React.createRef();
            embellishmentRefs.push(ref);
        });
    })
```

I am however getting stuck on how I should refactor this:

```
const ref: React.RefObject<AddArtEmbellishmentEntry> = React.createRef();
embellishmentRefs.push(ref);
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell of the code in your question, it appears you are trying to create an array of React refs. You will need to use the `useRef` hook to store the array of the other refs you are creating. From here, each render cycle map over the `embellishments` array and create a React ref if one hasn't already been created, and set the current `embellishmentRefs` value with the mapped array.

Example:

```
const embellishmentRefs = React.useRef<AddArtEmbellishmentEntry[]>([]);

const embellishments = Object.assign(
  [],
  props.orderLinesDetailed[0].embellishments
);

embellishmentRefs.current = embellishments.map(
  (_, i) => 
    embellishmentRefs.current[i] ?? React.createRef<AddArtEmbellishmentEntry>()
);
```